# Make administrator create users from a specific role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been reading about asp web administration tool. I read about creating roles and stuff and forcing a controller to use authentication in order to be viewed. My question is, say  create on the administration tool a user called Peter and I assign him the Administrator role. Then I want to create another role called LimitedAdministrator. But I want Peter to create new users on his View (I'm using MVC). Can anyone point me in the direction of how to do this.

I want peter to see on his page, like "Create user" and this user will be created as a LimitedAdministrator.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your question? I don't understand what you've written.

Comment: @Gabe - I think @bb2 wants to make some sort of "role management" where (s)he can add/delete new roles and give each role permissions -> ex. "Journalist" might Add/Delete news articles, but should not be able to do anything fancy such as user management etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably handle this by limiting the available roles that display on the page for Peter to choose from.  You'd also need to validate that the role passed in the request is a valid role for Peter to create as well.  Say you're using a dropdown to allow Peter to choose roles for new users.  Then simply populate the dropdown with only those roles which Peter has access to assign using whatever logic is used to make that decision.  If Peter can only allocate LimitedAdministrators, then you don't need to present him with a choice, just apply that role server side based on your logic for Peter.

If you do it this way, you won't need to have separate pages/views for each type of administrative user.  You can reuse the view because you're changing the data in the model.  The view displays the proper data according to the model corresponding with the user's capabilities.

Comment: How can I link that role automatically. The thing is I want a normal view, so that I user creates his account as a role "normal". Then peter the admin creates accounts for users with the role "limitedadmin", yes i can handle this like "behind the scenes" but where can i find info on how to do this?

Comment: @bb2 - Roles are just data -- a person having a role just means that there's a relationship between a role and that person.  What you need is a set of interfaces to manage these relationships.  Protect the actions so that only users already in appropriate roles can use them.  So, for example, Peter sees a link on a user's page to "account/editrole" with that user's user id as the id parameter.  This shows a page where Peter can change the user's role.  On the account/register (or create) page if the user is an admin you use a dropdown to allow "LimitedAdmin" or "Normal", etc.